# How can people download an iPhone app from my website to their iPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari

I'm developing an iPhone app to share locally with friends. I need a way to get it on their phones, and this is the only free way I know, but I'm not sure how do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow you to simply <kbd>Download</kbd> apps from your website. Apple is much more strict in how you can download apps and does not allow this.

However the cost is [$99 USD per year for a developer account:](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)

> The Apple Developer Program is 99 USD per membership year or in local currency where available.

Which you can enroll [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/).

This account gives you many [features that you don't get with a standard Apple ID including:](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

- App distribution
- Access to beta releases
- Safari extentions

However if you would rather choose to make an Android App you have a number of bonus features that you would not get if you went with Apple:

You dont need to pay $99 USD per year. Google only requires you to pay a one time fee of $25 USD for a "Publisher Account".

> Pay a $25 USD registration fee using Google payments. If you don't have a Google payments account, you can quickly set one up during the process.

And if you want any sort of payment.. ie: paid apps, in app-purchases, etc. It seems that google allows you to set up a merchant account for free.

However keep in mind: **Android doesn't requre you to publish your app to test it.** And you also don't need a "Publisher Account" to test apps on your phone or device! You can do that for free on any Android phone.

This means that you can put you apk onto your website and android users can download and install it!

However if you want to do it with Apple you need a "Developer Account" as far as I know at least. I don't think there is any way to get your app able to download for free (however I have not done much research on this topic, so you may want to).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Ill look into it, Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Trixter No problem! If my answer solves your question (and you dont get another answer that better soves it) please consider pressing the checkmark next to my answer. This says "Yes this answer best solves my question".... And also please consider pressing the up arrow next to my answer, this upvotes my answer which means "Yes this user has posted a good quality answer".. And it gives me some reputation on this site! I suggest you give some time before (if at all ) you decide to choose an answer / upvote to see if you get a better answer from someone else! Either way, good luck!